# Hudson build failed using Python & Coverage

Tags: python, continuous-integration, hudson, code-coverage, python-coverage

I completed [this tutorial](http://www.rhonabwy.com/wp/2009/11/04/setting-up-a-python-ci-server-with-hudson/comment-page-1/#comment-102826) from Joe Heck to set up **Hudson** for **Python**. Everything worked perfectly except the **Coverage** section.  My build failed with this output:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6222564272447222496.sh
+ coverage run tests/run.py --with-xunit
You must specify at least one of -e, -x, -c, -r, or -a.
```

I tried to include the Execute argument, -x, but got an exception that was ultimately caused by a permissions failure:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'nosetests.xml'
```

Has anyone gotten **Coverage** working successfully with **Hudson**?

Comment: This doesn't seem particular to Hudson - your coverage tool just isn't working.  What happens when you run that command outside of Hudson?

Comment: +1 For the great link. I've just followed the tutorial through, and it works fine for me (coverage version 3.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an old version of coverage.py, it looks like 2.x of some sort.  "coverage run" is new syntax with coverage.py 3.x.  Download the latest coverage.py at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage, and you should be good to go.

Comment: At first, I couldn't figure out why I couldn't get the latest version of coverage installed. Then I realized the root problem was with my setuptools.  I had version 0.6c9 (Ubuntu 9.1). To get coverage 3.2, 0.6c11 has to be installed. Visit http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and install manually rather than using Ubuntu's aptitude or apt-get python-tools.